# basic_thread_pool is not a member of boost::executors

Tags: c++, boost

I am changing the version of boost to 1.71 from boost 1.63 and while running against the projects and solutions i see the following error in multiple places. Below is how I have used it:

```
      boost::executors::basic_thread_pool threadPool( workingThreadNum );
```

The error that I see:

C2039   'basic_thread_pool': is not a member of 'boost::executors' on the above line.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These features are experimental and require compiler defines to enable their conditional compilation:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION 1
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE

#include <boost/thread/executors/basic_thread_pool.hpp>
```

Of course it's important for these to be

- defined *before* inclusion of the first related header
- defined **exactly the same** for any object participating in a link

Therefore I highly suggest defining it at the build-configuration level with something like (depending on your build tooling):

```
CPPFLAGS+=-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION=1
CPPFLAGS+=-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS=1
CPPFLAGS+=-DBOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE=1
```